# Tring to pull text from a DIV element

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

I've tried a couple ways to locate the test for "No matches found". i'm trying to capture "No matches found".

The CSS path is "#searchResultsWarningMessageBox > table > tbody > tr > td.messageCell > div"

```
WebElement txtMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchResultsWarningMessageBox > table > tbody > tr > td.messageCell > div > class.messageText"));


WebElement txtMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchResultsWarningMessageBox > table > tbody > tr > td.messageCell > div));
```

class="messageTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">No matches found

Any thoughts / hints?

Comment: post your related html snippet in your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that this div has text and your CSS path (if not, provide html source of the element, you want to get text from), like `<div>desired_text</div>`, then to retrieve the text you need to call `getText()` method:

```
WebElement txtMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchResultsWarningMessageBox > table > tbody > tr > td.messageCell > div > class.messageText"));

String divText = txtMsg.getText();
```

BTW, in your second example, you forgot to resolve quotes:

```
WebElement txtMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchResultsWarningMessageBox > table > tbody > tr > td.messageCell > div));
```

fix to:

```
WebElement txtMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchResultsWarningMessageBox > table > tbody > tr > td.messageCell > div"));
```